# Optimal data store memory usage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm in the process of building a data store for keeping track of all the remote images being stored in my app.  I've decided to use a singleton that will keep track of all the images being referenced.

As I remember, iOS automatically begins purging objects from memory based on recency of usage, whether or not it's being referenced by the current view controller, etc.  However, if I store these images in a data store, those objects are always being referenced by the store itself.  My solution for memory management was to keep track of when images were last called and keep some form of limit on the # and size of images being stored in the data store and purge the oldest based on age.

**Is this solution a good one?  Why or why not?  Should I be depending on Apple's automatic memory management, or is having my own manager fine?**

*Further explanation:*

Here's how requesting an image from one of my view controllers will end up looking with my solution:

```
[[HollerImages store]getImageWithUrl:@"https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png" 
                     completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image){
                        if( succeeded ){
                            //Update the UIImageView with the returned image
                        }
                     }];
```

The store will then manage how many images are currently being referenced in the app and automatically de-reference old images as we hit some pre-defined limit.  Thoughts?

Comment: «As I remember, iOS automatically begins purging objects from memory based on recency of usage,» It's not clear what you're talking about here. iOS will purge _applications_ (which have been backgrounded), but it doesn't directly touch the memory space of an individual app. It'll send a "warning", and it's _your_ responsibility to reduce your usage by whatever scheme you find best.

Comment: Got it ... however there is a limitation on memory usage, no?  What happens if you exceed that limit?  You can't just ignore the warnings as far as I know.

Comment: The limit is dynamic -- it depends on what's happening. If there's memory pressure, the system sends a memory warning to running processes, then (if it didn't recover enough memory) starts purging backgrounded apps. If it still can't find enough memory, your app will be terminated without further notice. You can indeed ignore the warnings, but at your own peril. The OS never manages your objects, though -- it only works at the level of entire processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaud Boisjoly (@rboisjoly) just sent me a link to this library which appears to provide the solution I was describing: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle memory concerns is to just implement the `-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` function and clear out all your cached data there.

What you're talking about is implementing an expiring cache. You could just count the elements in your data structure at each insertion and remove elements from the head when you've hit the limit (provided it is an ordered data structure). The former solution is easier and works in most cases.